# Cant save files like before in the new PhpStorm 2016

Tags: editor, phpstorm, remote-host

I am using PhpStorm 2016 for some weeks now and I am facing a weird behavior with some of my downloaded files. In most of them I can save with `Ctrl + S` but in some, I must hit the upload button (top right). I already checked the documentation and google but cant find something to help.

Please give me a hint in how I can redownload these files correctly.

In the left is the way I want to achieve (no toolbar)

[image: Opened files]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I just found out. If I double click on file in the remote host sidebar, the file is opened like in the right. If I double click on file in the project sidebar, the file is opened like in the left.